# Google Drive Export file with supportsAllDrives

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy a file locally with Google Drive API with the following code:

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('My API');
    $client->setScopes([
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY,
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY,
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
        ]);
    $client->setAuthConfig(GOOGLE_SA_JSON);
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file = $service->files->get(GOOGLE_STRAINS_DOC_ID, ["supportsAllDrives" => true]);
    $response = $service->files->export($file->getId(), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'myAPI');
    file_put_contents($temp_file, $response->getBody()->getContents());
```

I suspect it has something to do with "supportsAllDrives" not being passed with the export function...

The response is this:

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Export only supports Docs Editors files.", "errors": [ { "message": "Export only supports Docs Editors files.", "domain": "global", "reason": "fileNotExportable" } ] } }
```

The file is exportable and is a google "Excel" sheet,

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- "Method: files.export" has no parameter of `supportsAllDrives`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export)
- About `Export only supports Docs Editors files.`, in this case, it is considered that you are trying to download a file except for Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides, and so on). From `The file is exportable and is a google "Excel" sheet,`, is this XLSX file? In that case, such an error occurs.

If you want to download both Google Docs files and other files, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```php
$file = $service->files->get(GOOGLE_STRAINS_DOC_ID, ["supportsAllDrives" => true]);
$response = $service->files->export($file->getId(), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'myAPI');
file_put_contents($temp_file, $response->getBody()->getContents());
```

##### To:

```php
$file = $service->files->get(GOOGLE_STRAINS_DOC_ID, ["supportsAllDrives" => true]);
$fileId = $file->getId();
$mimeType=$file->getMimeType();
echo $mimeType;
if (strpos($mimeType, "application/vnd.google-apps") !== false) {
    if ($mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
        $response = $service->files->export($fileId, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'myAPI');
        file_put_contents($temp_file, $response->getBody()->getContents());
    }
} else {
    $response = $service->files->get($fileId, ["supportsAllDrives" => true, "alt" => "media"]);
    file_put_contents($file->getName(), $response->getBody());
}
```

- By this modification, when the file of `GOOGLE_STRAINS_DOC_ID` is one of the Google Docs files and the Spreadsheet, Spreadsheet is downloaded as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. This is from your showing script. When the file of `GOOGLE_STRAINS_DOC_ID` is not the Google Docs file, the file is directly downloaded.

#### Note:

- If you want to download only XLSX file, you can also use the following script.

  ```php
  $response = $service->files->get("###fileId###", ["supportsAllDrives" => true, "alt" => "media"]);
  file_put_contents("filename.xlsx", $response->getBody());
  ```

#### References:

- [Download & export files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)
- [Method: files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export)